# Storing clients data efficiently

Tags: python, client-server, storage

I'm developing a client-server app to distribute and execute code in multiple clients. This is how it must to work:

1. Clients connect to the server sending their status each minute.
2. Server store clients IPs and status.
3. Someone send a code to be executed to the server.
4. The server searches for a free and active client and sends the code.

My problem with this is the amount of clients that I can handle. I was thinking in use lists to store clients objects or something similar but I could have thousands of clients so maybe is not a good idea because I'll run out of resources. Which could be the best option to store all clients data efficiently without hang the server?

Sorry for not to show any code but I'm in the designing step currently and I'm stuck with this. The project will be developed using Python but I don't need code.

Comment: This sounds a bit like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Comment: I haven't heard about Celery before but seems that it is used to process tasks. My real problem is storing clients data and work with it fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just worried about not having enough memory to keep all the Python data, you could pickle it and keep track of eg just the ID and the pickled file, [Python Docs Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Another good example is [Shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html).

The upside to both of these is not having to worry about serializing or modelling your data on eg an SQL database.

Of course, you could go for a combination of the two. Pickle the data and save the resulting string in a field in a database. This way, you can simply add columns with meta data if you need in the future. When it comes to the speed consideration, you either keep it in a database so you can query it nicely, or keep it as files in order to get rid of that "overhead". Be careful about premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I don't have any problem with modelling the data on a database. I'm not doing that because maybe is too slower that use memory or files. As I said, the real problem is the performance. I'll have to process a lot of requests and updates. One part of the code is focused in force clients synchronization to not send updates at the same moment but even with that I'll have a lot of traffic.

Comment: If you don't have any need of querying the data etc, serializing the data directly into files using pickle or the slightly smarter shelve is the way to go, for sure.

Comment: Actually I don't have the need but in a future I could add a website to show clients statuses and code being processed.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía updated my answer to reflect the fact that you could just combine the two, and a note about efficiency

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite is a lite database storage and efficient, or use mongoDB(no sql database), if you don't like mysql

http://www.sqlite.org/

http://www.mongodb.org/

i assume that they are more faster than mysql...

Comment: Currently I have a simple and stupid tiny app that uses a list but I have only three clients so I don't have any problem. The tricky part is when I'll have thousands of clients. I can't store so many info in a list and maybe use a database is not efficiently enough to process all information. Probably I'am wrong. I'm only asking because my knowledge about this are really limited.

Comment: databases - are just files that store data in binary formats, they are designed for best performance, the same will happen if you will store data in files but i assume it will work more slower than if you were using a database, all of the most popular applications are using databases, perhaps some experts are Remaking those databases for they own needs, like google for example they use mysql, but i far as i know, they had modificated the algoritm of mysql....